kivy/Buildozer read/write text documents
I am attempting to create a text editor for android.
I am writing it in python and then converting it with buildozer.
My problem is that the "Save" button seems to do nothing at all.
It asks for permissions on startup, but only for Music and Photos.
I am unable to load text documents.
Logs are also not being generated - it seems as though the "Download" folder cannot be found.
Here is the script:
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.utils import platform
from plyer import filechooser
import os
import logging

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)

class Editor(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.orientation = 'horizontal'
        self.text_input = TextInput(font_name="pixelated_font.ttf", font_size=20, background_color=(0, 0, 0, 1), foreground_color=(0, 255, 0, 1))
        self.add_widget(self.text_input)

        self.save_btn = Button(text='Save', on_press=self.save_text, size_hint=(1.0, 0.1))
        self.load_btn = Button(text='Load', on_press=self.load_text, size_hint=(1.0, 0.1))
        self.add_widget(self.save_btn)
        self.add_widget(self.load_btn)

    def save_text(self, instance):
        try:
            path = filechooser.save_file(title="Save your file", filters=[("Text files", "*.txt")])
            if path and path[0]:
                with open(path[0], 'w') as file:
                    file.write(self.text_input.text)
                logging.info('File saved successfully.')
            else:
                logging.info('Save file operation cancelled.')
        except Exception as e:
            logging.error(f"Error saving file: {e}")

    def load_text(self, instance):
        try:
            path = filechooser.open_file(title="Open your file", filters=[("Text files", "*.txt")])
            if path and path[0]:
                with open(path[0], 'r') as file:
                    self.text_input.text = file.read()
                logging.info('File loaded successfully.')
            else:
                logging.info('Load file operation cancelled.')
        except Exception as e:
            logging.error(f"Error loading file: {e}")

class RetroTextEditorApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Editor()

    def on_start(self):
        if platform == 'android':
            from android.permissions import request_permissions, Permission, check_permission
            request_permissions([Permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE], self.permissions_callback)

    def permissions_callback(self, permissions, results):
        if all(results):
            logging.info("All permissions granted.")
        else:
            logging.info("One or more permissions were denied.")
            # Handle the case where permissions are not granted

if __name__ == '__main__':
    RetroTextEditorApp().run()

